# Structure of class group of quadratic forms negative discriminant

Tags: quadratic-forms, ideal-class-group

I am trying to work out the structure of the class groups for discriminants of some simple forms.

I am interested in the cases where the discriminant is a prime number and where it is of the form $d = p_1 p_2^2 \dots p_n^2$
for $p_i$ primes.

The class number for these discriminants has a simple form and so I am wondering if this extends to the structure of the group in any way.

Comment: I like Buell, Binary Quadratic Forms. Pages 117-118, he compares $h(\Delta)$ and $h( \Delta p^2)$ for odd prime $p.$ Then Theorem 7.5 on page 118 is $h(4 \Delta).$ Also, I recently bought Quadratic Number Theory by J. L. Lehman; he goes through the whole song and dance of form classes and ideal classes.

Comment: The above seems to be special cases of Theorem 2.17 in the following: http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~buzzard/maths/research/notes/Yukako_Kezuka_MSc_Project.pdf - I am essentially looking to use the relation between the size of their form class groups in order to ascertain a relation between the structure of their form class groups

Comment: Buzzard is good. What is your background?

Comment: Currently doing a masters although I do not have a strong background in this area - I have taken some courses in alg NT although they haven't focused specifically on quadratic forms or on the structure of class groups

Comment: Alright, Buell published in searching for more elaborate groups. That's mostly chapter 8, he does the Cohen-Lenstra heuristics. He gives a table of groups he found on page 154, more on page 156.  And chapter 9 is about the 2-Sylow subgroup. Tell you what, take a look at http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/inhom.cgi   as well as http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/  which is mostly about ternary forms